# Leverage browser caching for external files in Windows server

Tags: javascript, caching, browser

As per the Google's page speed suggestions I am trying to leverage browser cache, But the hinderences are the external files

http://banners.copyscape.com/images/cs-wh-234x16.gif (expiration not specified)
http://platform.twitter.com/js/tfw/hub/client.js (expiration not specified)
http://cdn.api.twitter.com/..imous.com%2F&callback=twttr.receiveCount (15 minutes)
http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js (30 minutes)
http://www.google.com/…...=en (60 minutes)
http://www.hittail.com/mlt.js (4 hours)

Is there anyway to achieve this in Windows server?